# server unresponsive after configuring raid 1

Tags: centos, raid

On a brand new server I've got 2 SSD discs that are by default configured to RAID 1 and 2 6TB discs that are not.
The 6TB discs are identified as `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`

I've run these commands ([taken from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350266/how-can-i-create-a-raid-array-with-2tb-disks#answer-463813)):

```
 parted /dev/sdc
 mklabel gpt
 print free(max size iz 6001GB)
 mkpart primary 1M 6001GB
```

Followed by:

```
parted /dev/sdd
mklabel gpt
print free(max size iz 6001GB)
mkpart primary 1M 6001GB
```

Followed by:

```
sudo mdadm --verbose --create /dev/md4 --level=raid1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sd[cd]1
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/md4
sudo mkdir /mnt/md4
```

I appended to `/etc/fstab` this line:

```
 /dev/md4 /mnt/md4 auto defaults 0 0
```

and finished with `sudo mount /mnt/md4`

I've also waited for discs to finish resyncing, but I am still unable to ssh into the server using normal mode.
Results of `cat /proc/mdstat` command:

[image]

That is the result of `lsblk` command I was able to run in rescue mode (not really sure how it differs from normal mode):

[image]

After reboot, server never comes up again as any ssh connection is timed out. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am running centos 7.

UPDATE:

Output of `ssh -vvv root@IP`:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname IP is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port 22.
debug1: connect to address IP port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host IP port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: I don't think your disks have anything to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Apart from `yum update`, these are the only command I've run so I assumed disks had something to do with it.

Comment: *After reboot, server never comes up again as any ssh connection is timed out.* Please edit your question and post `ssh -vvv server output` (you may need to hide your real IP addresses). I think it's due to firewall.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Output added

Comment: *connect to address IP port 22: Operation timed out* - that's indicative of a firewall or misconfigured network. Your disks are unlikely to to do anything with that.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

> `connect to address IP port 22: Operation timed out`

That's indicative of a firewall or misconfigured network. Your disks are unlikely to to do anything with that.

*It's also indicative of a server that's powered off, or didn't reboot properly (e.g. either grub didn't load, or grub wasn't able to load the kernel - either of which could be due to the re-partitioning and re-configuration of the drives as RAID devices), or is not responding for some other reason. The only way to know for sure is to have someone physically present at the console (or use some kind of out-of-band management connection, such as IPMI or KVM-over-IP to get remote console access).* @cas

Comment: It's also indicative of a server that's powered off, or didn't reboot properly (e.g. either grub didn't load, or grub wasn't able to load the kernel - either of which *could* be due to the re-partitioning and re-configuration of the drives as RAID devices), or is not responding for some other reason.   The only way to know for sure is to have someone physically present at the console (or use some kind of out-of-band management connection, such as [IPMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) or KVM-over-IP to get remote console access).

Answer (score 0):

Issue went away after OS reinstallation.

After reinstallation, disks were already partitioned so all I did was to

`mkfs.ext4 /dev/md4`, copied UUID from `blkid /dev/md4`, appended `UUID=xx /storage ext4 rw,noatime 0 0` to `/etc/fstab` and `mount -a`